# can fonts for SVG elements be declared in CSS file?

Tags: css, svg, fonts

is there any way we can define/change/set font attributes for SVG elements from a linked CSS file?  or does all that data have to be fixed into the SVG file itself?  emphasis on 'fixed'.  ick.

in other words, would doing something like the following be valid?

the SVG:

```
<svg>
  <g id="buttonText">
    <text id="buttonTextShadow">CLICK ME</text>
    <text id="buttonTextColor">CLICK ME</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

the CSS:

```
#buttonTextColor, #buttonTextShadow  { font-family: "OpenSans"; }
#buttonTextColor { color: #fff; }
#buttonTextShadow { color: #333; }
```

it would be nice to be able to target and style these things from a stylesheet...  if not, i'll adapt... :P

TIA!

WR!

Comment: Didn't you try it and find it worked? Except for the fact that color is not a property that's used by SVG of course.

Comment: nope.  nothing worked.  i figured i was just missing something, so i came here.  i'm just starting to dig a little deeper into the SVG, so there's a lot i don't yet know.  and i don't want to waste time on things i don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work and you can target the `id`s directly if you wish.

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
        font-family: "OpenSans";
        src: url('/path/to/font.woff');
      }

      #buttonText {
        font-family: "OpenSans";
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="buttonText">
    <text id="buttonTextShadow">CLICK ME</text>
    <text id="buttonTextColor">CLICK ME</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: so it all has to be contained within the SVG itself.  no external CSS?

Comment: You can use an @import statement in there as well, to an external Google font, etc.

Comment: !!  good to know.  but at the end of the day, everything needs to be within the SVG itself.  no external stylesheets or javascript functions...  bummer.